# How do I set up QT Creator to use launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, bazaar, qt-creator

I've created an UbuntuTouch program using QTCreator, and I'd like to set it up to store it in launchpad.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Register your project here: https://launchpad.net/projects/+new
2. Push to your project: `bzr push lp:projectname`

   If the name of your project is `myprogram` then the URL to push to is `bzr push lp:myprogram`

This assumes you already have a Launchpad account and you have authorized your SSH key. If that's not the case, these are the steps to get that done too:

1. On Launchpad homepage click on **Login in / Register** in the top-right corner
2. On your profile homepage, click on the pencil icon next to **SSH keys**
3. Copy and paste your SSH *public key* in the **Add an SSH key** box. Your SSH public key is usually in the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on your computer.
4. Tell your `bzr` command your Launchpad user id, so that when you run `bzr push` or `bzr commit` commands on a Launchpad URL it can make the association between your PC account and your Launchpad account:

   ```
   bzr lp-login yourlpusername
   ```

   Where `yourlpusername` is the username you created on Launchpad.

Comment if any of this doesn't work as expected!